# I’m looking to know some chassidus songs

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, music

I am trying to find some well Niggunim of Poilishe Chassidim. Names along with places to listen to them would be greatly appreciated,Thank you.

Comment: Any niggunim of Ger, Vizhnitz or Bobov.

Comment: When you say "Niggunim" do you mean specifically those without words, or also songs with words?

Comment: Including those with words

Answer (score 3):

The Modzitzer Chassidus is famous for its niggunim, some of which the Rebbes throughout the ages composed. Modzitz and its history of niggunim have been made famous [over the years](https://www.npr.org/2013/10/16/235525531/the-greatest-living-figure-of-chasidic-music) thanks to [Ben Zion Shenker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Zion_Shenker) - you can find many of them on Mostly Music including:

- [Niggunei Modzits 5769](https://mostlymusic.com/products/modzitz-5769-cd?variant=1037277565)
- [Niggunei Modzitz 5767](https://mostlymusic.com/products/modzitz-5767-cd?variant=1037277613)
- [Modzitz Niggunim - Volume 3](https://mostlymusic.com/products/nigunim-volume-3-cd?variant=1037277545)
- [Modzitzer Oitzres](https://mostlymusic.com/products/modzitzer-oitzres-2-bikurei-zimra-series?variant=6853926715446)
- [Modzitzer Oitzres 2](https://mostlymusic.com/products/modzitzer-oitzres-2-bikurei-zimra-series?variant=6853976490038)
- [Ben Zion Shenker - A Shabbos in Modzitz 1](https://mostlymusic.com/products/a-shabbos-in-modzitz-1-uveyom-hashabbos-cd)
- [Ben Zion Shenker - A Shabbos in Modzitz 2: Me'ein Olam Habah](https://mostlymusic.com/products/a-shabbos-in-modzitz-2-meein-olam-habah-cd?variant=1037316989)
- [Ben Zion Shenker - A Shabbos in Modzitz 3: Ki Va Moed](https://mostlymusic.com/products/a-shabbos-in-modzitz-3-ki-ba-moed-cd?variant=1037316925)
- [Ben Zion Shenker - A Shabbos in Modzitz 4: Melaveh Malka](https://mostlymusic.com/products/a-shabbos-in-modzitz-4-melaveh-malka-cd?variant=1037316877)

and many more...